# python regexp for format-strings with '%s, %s'

Tags: python, regex, format-string

I'm migrating my Python2-scripts to Python3 and trying to use Python3 regexes, but don't have sufficient experience in this field.

There are many strings of the following kind:

```
print("%s" % error_msg)
```

These are matched by the pattern

```
'^(\s*)print\("([^%]*)%[dhos]([^%]*)" % ([^\)]*(?=\)))\)'
```

suffiecently well.

I did not find yet a pattern which fully matches lines of this second kind:

```
logg.debug("in_file: %s, %s" % (in_file, out_file) )
```

These are (nearly ;-) matched by the pattern

```
'^(\s*)print\("([^%]*)%[dhos]([^%]*)" % ([^\)]*(?=\)))\)'
```

leaving out the closing parenthesis of the tuple;
with an additional 'if'-clause I can solve this case.

The siuation gets a bit more complicated with lines of this third type:

```
print("partinf_tup: %s, %s" % (access_name, repr(partinf_tup)) )
```

Any solution for this case?
TIA
Hellmut

Comment: Sorry for an error in my first post. The second pattern I gave is not correct ,-( I really use '^(\s*)print\("([^%]*)%[dhos]([^%]*)%[dhos]([^%]*)" % \(([^,]+), ([^\)]+)\)'.

Comment: Your use case is slightly puzzling. Python regexes didn't change much between versions 2 and 3, nor did format strings; in either case, there are automated tools like `2to3` which can translate code automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be only a single optional pair of parenthesis after matching  `%`

```
\b(?:print|logg\.debug)\("[^%"]*%[^"]*" % [^()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?[^()]*\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:print|logg\.debug)` Match one of the alternatives
- `\("` Match `("`
- `[^%"]*` Optionally match any char except `%` `"`
- `%[^"]*" %`  Match `%` followed by optionally matching any char except `"` and then match `" %`
- `[^()]*` Optionally match any char except `(` `)`
- `(?:\([^()]*\))?` Optionally match from opening till closing parenthesis `(...)`
- `[^()]*\)` Match optional chars other than `(` `)` and match the closing `)`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY7Fd7/1).

For an arbitrary number of nested parenthesis, you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) making use of recursion:

```
\b(?:print|logg\.debug)\("[^%"]*%[^"]*" % [^()]*(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\)))?[^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MmmApe/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##VZDdioMwEIWvzVMMASFjRSh7Vyg@iKlibbSBmoRJhF3ou7sxusvuTX7P@c5w3Fd4WvOxrnp2lgKQmtQnY64PQZGBKxCXd1FfHGkT3i87TbJ6qPsyoRSSN20u@a3Im3bbJIccmlbgrYgOIUVc0/V0eov6jFhIRKx3hUTOmI8Bgid2pOU@ERSRpW72McJIw1nGt9g9Naq06Ub9UhfIfQmHRRyPJdglpBPCr/sH73oK2oxdWNx/cz8MyvvO9HMEkHIk/kgxkjgyNvdheKpt4FRRNWrz0LEjcVRVgo@q0RJ0JSQxaAPKLLOiPihx@KMsRPj1jBeW7ZOln2oiuziBmK3rNw)